# Java / JavaFX - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in a short and relatively simple programm

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list, out-of-memory

I am currently working on a JavaFX application and am trying to implement a function that converts a string of any length, which contains numbers separated by empty spaces, into integers. I am pretty sure the function I wrote should work, although for some reason, I am getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" errors.

I am using Java and JavaFX version 17!

My Function:

```
// Create an empty LinkedList to store the converted integers.
LinkedList<Integer> inputList = new LinkedList<>();


public void StringtoInteger(String strInput) {
    int emptySpace = 0; // This variable keeps track of the index of the empty space.
    int endString = strInput.length(); // The size of the input string.
    String str; // Temporary string variable to hold substrings.

    // Iterate over the input string to extract substrings.
    for(int x=0; x<endString; x = emptySpace + 1) {
        emptySpace = strInput.indexOf(" ", x); // Find the index of the next empty space.

        if (emptySpace != -1) {
            str = strInput.substring(x, emptySpace); // Extract the substring from the start to the empty space.
        } else {
            str = strInput.substring(x); // If no empty space is found, extract the remaining substring.
        }

        inputList.add(Integer.parseInt(str.trim())); // Convert the substring to an integer and add it to the LinkedList.
    }
}
```

My Main is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testHeap = "5 6 1 7 12 21 58";
    StringtoInteger(testHeap);
    System.out.println(inputList);
}
```

The full Error message is as follows

```
ERROR!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:4030)
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:715)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1879)
    at ExampleClass.stringToInteger(ExampleClass.java:15)
    at ExampleClass.main(ExampleClass.java:26)
```

I tried reallocating the memory my program uses, but it just keeps crashing or showing me the error.
If I run the program in IntelliJ, it crashes. If I run the function explicitly in a separate Java environment, it shows the error message.

Thanks for any help beforehand.

Comment: Removed JavaFX tag as it not relevant.

Comment: thanks a lot!
adding a break is indeed the answer, i feels so stupid overlooking this.

Comment: Actually, adding a `break` is not a particularly good solution. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because you don't terminate the loop when there are no more spaces in the string.

When this happens, as your code acknowledges with the `if (emptySpace != -1)` clause, `emptySpace` will be `-1`. The loop modification clause `x = emptySpace + 1` then sets `x` to `0`, and the process starts from the beginning of the string. Consequently, you just add elements to the list indefinitely.

This is a good example of trying to reinvent potentially tricky algorithms that are already implemented by the API. You should always use API methods where possible. [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) already implements splitting a string into parts at a delimiter:

```
public void stringtoInteger(String strInput) {
    for (String str : strInput.split(" ")) {
        inputList.add(Integer.parseInt(str.trim())); // Convert the substring to an integer and add it to the LinkedList.
    }
}
```